# How can I include Hangul and Hanja in a website?

Tags: hangul

I am building a website using Hangul and Hanja. What is the best way to incorporate those characters in my computer code so that they render appropriately in web browsers?

Are there any specific software-type programs used in Korea to build Korean language websites? For example, I know Microsoft Word can be used in Korean, but there is also the word processing program Hangul, which is used by many people.

Thank you!

Comment: Please consider [accepting](https://korean.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) an [answer](https://korean.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) if you have found it helpful

Comment: Uh, [_Stack Overflow_](https://stackoverflow.com/)?

Answer (score 7):

Korean (Chinese, Japanese) characters are [multibyte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748965/what-is-a-multibyte-character-set).  Whenever dealing with multibyte characters, the recommendation is for your site encoding to use [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

`<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

And as @teddy-cross notes, the [HTML5, arguably equivalent but shorter version may be preferable since it's easier to remember; and yet, in many cases the absence of Content-Type in the server side header would make using the longer version preferable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type):

`<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">`

As far as "what software should I use to create my website"...that is a discussion for another area outside Korean Language SE.  Nevertheless, there may be [some tips here](http://www.kanjidatabase.com/japanese_developer_tips.php) that will assist you.

Good luck!

Comment: The standard way to set the charset is simpler: `<meta charset="utf-8">` note that it must be the first tag in the `<head>` in order to load correctly.

Comment: @teddy-cross since the longer version has been with me since XHTML and was still validating, it was quietly in need of your comment to wake me up to the possibilities there.  thank you.